# How to draw multiple arrows in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm having problems in drawing a diagram with multiple arrows between given two objects. For instance,

```
 \begin{tikzcd}
   A \arrow{r}{i_1} &C \arrow{l}{\pi_1}  \arrow{r}{\pi_2}  &B \arrow{l}{1_2}
 \end{tikzcd}
```

In this case, the arrows i_1 and \pi_1 overlap each other. 
 In it possible to draw multiple arrows (in the sense above mentioned) using tikz-cd?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option you need is called `shift left` or `shift right` and can be added to every arrow with or without any measure. E.g. `\arrow[shift right=5]{r}{i}`. In your example, the default `[shift left]` looks just right. In your very case, you need the same shift for every arrow. That's why I just appended it to every of them. If you need other arrows in your diagram, you will have to kick out the global option and set it locally as shown above.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
 \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={shift left}]
 A \arrow{r}{i_1} &C \arrow{l}{{\pi\vphantom{1}}_1}  \arrow{r}{\pi_2}  &B \arrow{l}{1_2}
 \end{tikzcd}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what does `shift` do, and why `left` or `right`?  I thought it should be `shift up` or `down`?

Comment: @YanKingYin The shift is applied in the direction of the arrow it self. Like this, it will fit for any arrow direction. In the image you can see that every arrow has been shifted a bit to the left regarding its normal centric position. I have not given any measure so that `tikz-cd` takes the default shifting value. You may do something like `shift left=3cm` as well. Wile writing this, I noticed that this is all described in my answer above. Please let me know, if something stays unclear.

Comment: Ah... epiphany!! :)